# C# Open a link in private mode in FireFox

Tags: c#, firefox

How can I open a link in private mode in Firefox?

I try this

```
Process.Start(@"firefox.exe", "--private http://google.com");
```

or

```
Process.Start(@"firefox.exe", "-private-window http://google.com");
```

but it doesn't work.

In chrome everything is working with that command

```
Process.Start(@"chrome.exe", "--incognito http://google.pl");
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Well, what does the Firefox command line option documentation say?

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? It's not opening at all, or opning, but not in private mode?

Comment: documentation say to open it -private-mode or -private but it only open Firefox in standard mode and even doesn't open a link, if I delete --private or -private-mode it opens a link.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really launch Firefox with a new url in a private window AFAIK. -private-window  will open a new private window, but still put the new tab in a regular one.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to open one page in private mode Process.Start(@"firefox.exe", "-private-window http://www.google.pl"); and how to open a new tab in this mode?